# Accessing Class Data from Declared Struct

Tags: c++

Alright, so I've tried a few ways to deal with this issue, but I can't seem to fix it.

In my header file I have:

```
class MyClass {
public:
  bool test;

  struct MyStruct;
};
```

I also have a constructor and all that, but that's not the important/not causing errors

In the cpp what I want to do is this:

```
MyClass::MyStruct {
  test=true;
};
```

The problem with this, is that the struct is unable to access the test variable. How can I pass the current instance's variable to the struct or some other way to allow the struct to access the variable.

Comment: It's not clear why you would need to do so: why test is not part of MyStruct? Which is your design?

Comment: @Antonio The bool in the class is used in a variety of functions, I didn't post the full code because it has many file dependencies from the game engine it's used in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me if MyStruct is executing code it should be a class.  And if so, you either pass it an instance of the MyClass (e.g. `this` if calling from MyClass), or pass it a reference to the member it needs (e.g. `this->test`)...

Comment: It can't be a class or have 'this' passed to it due to how other functions are using it. In my case, the struct is being used as a Type for another function which is accessing the struct's internal function execute() I can't mess with the constructor or the arguments for execute(), but I need the bool assignment to occur within the execute() block.

Comment: If you can't change the parameters to execute() (e.g. to pass an instance or member data), and the MyClass object is not global, then you have no was of accessing it (there is no "my parent object" kind of access).  Sounds like some kind of design/architecture change is in order...

Comment: It turns out that the functions had some extensions that do allow param passing, I managed to fix the issue. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
MyClass::MyStruct {
  test=true;
};
```

Is not at all valid C++ code.  Perhaps you meant this:

```
MyClass::Class() {
  test=true;
}
```

Which would make a default constructor of `MyClass` which sets `test` to `true`.  But your question makes it seem like you want to set the value of `MyClass::test` from `MyClass::MyStruct`.  This is not really possible, because a nested class (or struct, in your case) does not "inherit" or "contain" or really have almost any special relationship with its enclosing class (or struct).

Another possibility is this:

```
class MyClass {
public:
  static bool test;

  struct MyStruct;
};

MyClass::MyStruct::MyStruct() {
  test=true;
}
```

Which would make a default constructor of the nested struct which sets a variable in the enclosing class, but the variable then needs to be static, meaning there's only one in the whole program, not a separate value per instance of either class or struct.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the structure as a `friend` in the class definition.

```
class MyClass {
public:
  bool test;

  friend struct MyStruct;
};
```

**Edit:**

```
class MyClass {
   friend class MyStruct(MyClass *myClass) : myClass(myClass) {
      private:
      MyClass *myClass;
   }

   MyStruct *myStruct;

   bool test;

   public:

   MyClass() {
      myStruct = new MyStruct(this);
   }

}
```

Note: This is untested and just written in my browser. I know it's missing destructors and stuff.

Since you're passing the parent pointer to the member class, the member class can then access the parent class's private members because it was declared a `friend`.

Comment: I tried this, but it's still saying test is undefined in the struct.